# Displaying two separate Excel files on same map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, latitude-longitude, network

I have started to learn ArcMap.

I have two separate Excel files which are:
Border coordinates,
CSD coordinates.

For each Excel files, I have information for longtitude and latitude.
My aim is to see both border coordinates and CSD coordinates on same map in ArcMap. To see clearly which points are border, I want to make different colour for border coordinates than CSD coordinates.

Comment: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/maps-for-office/design-and-use/change-a-layer-s-style.htm

Comment: that link does not answer the question @csk

Comment: This question asks how to display two layers in different colors. If that's not what they're trying to ask, please [edit] the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ArcMap (and ArcGIS Pro) cannot read data in degrees-minutes-seconds
>   (DMS), and therefore this data must be converted into decimal degrees
>   (DD) before importing.
>
> The steps below give instructions for formatting XY data, in decimal
>   degrees, using Microsoft Excel, and converting these data to a
>   shapefile or geodatabase feature class in ArcMap.
>
> There are several table formats that ArcMap can read to bring point
>   data into ArcMap as an event theme.

Click File > Add Data > Add XY Data.

Select the table that contains x,y coordinate data.

Identify the columns that hold the x- and y-coordinates (and, optionally, the z-coordinate).

Specify the coordinate system.

[Adding x,y coordinate data as a layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm) can provide further assistance